# Is there any other definition or sub-meaning of the term 'marines'?

Tags: meaning, the-arrangement, elia-kazan

I've come across the term 'marines' in the book 'The Arrangement by Elia Kazan' twice; however I couldn't get what it may refer. I know it is like 'nautical' or something but it seemed different to me in the context. Need your help. Here are the two paragraphs:

> "You're the son of 612, aren't you?" he asked. "I'm Dr. Levine. I've been looking after your father."
>   "How is he really?" I said.
>   "He's finished. Otherwise he's fine."
>   "What the hell does that mean?"
>   "I t means some doctors will BS you, put him on a drug calendar,
>   and slip you a hefty bill. But there's no way back with this thing."
>   "So what do I do?"
>   "Make him as happy as you can, for as long as you can. But don't
>   look for the **marines**. They ain't coming."

I need to mention here that the old man here suffers from arteriosclerosis. The other paragraph is:

> My father winked at me, and laughed and coughed and laughed.
>   Miss Smythe came back. With her were Butch and the **marines**,
>   Dr. Levine and Father Draddy, the young priest who had tried to
>   talk to my father earlier and hadn't been able to.

I thought that the term 'marines' may be something used in daily language like white-collars or something like that. I know it isn't but what is it then?

Comment: Don't look for the marines - or don't wait for the cavalry - refers to Hollywood's habit of having earlier the cavalry, and later the marines show up at the last minute to rescue the movie's main characters.

A messenger might have been sent to seek help, but that's about realism, not plot necessity.  

Almost nothing separates that from the ancient theatrical conceit, 'deus ex machina' meaning that far from anything probable, the rescue relies on a God popping up - or on stage, being lowered out of a machine - and fixing everything through a liberal dose of handwavium.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While @Randal’Thor has given a literal definition of marines, the quotations show a more metaphorical usage.

Within American culture the Marines are the best fighters, the unstoppable yet noble force who will carry the day. To invoke the marines is to say that victory is assured. This is [illustrated in this quote](http://oldcorps.org/USMC/quotes.html)

> The Marines have landed and the situation is well in hand.

*Attributed to Richard Harding Davis (1864-1916)*

So to say ‘don’t look for the marines’ is to say that no-one is coming to make everything okay.

I would assume from the second quote that Dr Levine and Father Draddy *did* in some sense make everything okay and so are, metaphorically, the Marines.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it is like 'nautical' or something but it seemed different to me in the context.

It's more specific than that. The [marines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marines) are a special branch of the armed forces in many countries: naval infantry or 'soldiers at sea', sometimes operating as an autonomous part of the navy and sometimes as a separate fourth branch of the armed forces. In the context of this novel set in the United States, it would be the **United States Marine Corps**. You can [read about them on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Marine_Corps) or [follow them on Twitter](https://twitter.com/USMC).